# Random System.ArgumentException after a certain time while taking screenshots

Tags: c#, exception, argumentexception

My application runs fine for about 5 minutes, then it will throw some random `System.ArgumentException` as seen in the screenshot below:
[image]
The big problem here is that both arguments actually seem to be correct, and it works perfectly fine for about 5 minutes.
My application simply keeps taking snapshots of the screen in a separate Thread.

The following code takes the snapshot of the screen, and a `System.ArgumentException` is caused in this snippet (same as in the screenshot).

```
Bitmap SNew = new Bitmap(NewRes.Width, NewRes.Height);
using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(SNew))
    g.CopyFromScreen(0, 0, 0, 0, new Size(NewRes.Width, NewRes.Height));
```

---

The same exception may also occur at the `CopyFromScreen` method, with the same seemingly correct `NewRes` values (while not occuring at the first line in my snippet):

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in System.Drawing.dll
```

[image]

[image]

---

If I put this code in a `try { } catch { }` clause, it works *fine* as well (the exception does not occur anymore after the exception pops up in the log for about 10 times). This is of course not a great solution, and sometimes it just keeps hanging within that exception forever, not taking screenshots at all until I restart the application.

I have no idea why the arguments are invalid and what may cause this. Any ideas?

Comment: Are you calling Dispose on your Bitmap (and any other references to it) when you are finished with it?

Comment: This indeed "fixed" a part of the issue, now I'm getting out of memory after a longer time through CopyFromScreen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I can provide to you with certainty is a concrete alternative that will produce the same output but instead of using `CopyFromScreen` using `platform invoke` to interop with the Windows API directly. You can find a full example here, curtosy of [Hans Passant](https://stackoverflow.com/users/17034/hans-passant) as a response to a question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10233055/how-to-get-screenshot-to-include-the-invoking-window-on-xp/10234693#10234693).

I can't however, tell you with certainty why you're experiencing the exception but I can deduce from other sources such as [this thread](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/netfxbcl/thread/cedaa0f2-383c-4e61-92c0-c09123cb67cd/) (incidentally featuring Hans again as nobugz) and from my own experiences that `CopyFromScreen` is buggy and in this case, could be suffering from a memory leak. Considering the thread I linked, what version of the .NET Framework is your target framework?

Comment: I'm using .NET 3.5 which seems to cause such issues according to the linked topics. I'm testing your provided alternative now.

Comment: Together with a forgotten Dispose/using on a Bitmap object this has successfully fixed it. It ran for 3 hours straight now.